# App_global.asax.compiled and App_global.asax.dll missing from Publish Package

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an ASP.NET MVC application installed on 2 development computers. The application run fine on both computers (using local IIS). I often published on production server from one or the other computer without problems until recently. Since 3 weeks ago, only one computer allows me to publish successfully. When publishing from the other one (without errors) I got 403.14 errors when navigating on the published site. After searching four hours, I discovered that files `App_global.asax.compiled` and `App_global.asax.dll` where missing from the published Package folder.

When publishing from computer A : these 2 files are present

When publishing from computer B : these 2 files are missing and I got error 403.14 when navigating.

As suggested by some other people experiencing the same problem, I already compare every IIS settings and tried to disable my antivirus before publishing but without success.

The issue seems to be related to the "Publish" command. If published from computer B, it fails to include the `App_Global.asax.compiled` & `App_Global.asax.dll` in the bin directory

This behaviour is causing 403 errors upon loading to IIS. However, if I publish again but with the computer A (this time), it adds the two files back.

Maybe something corrupted on computer B but I don't know where to search.

**EDIT 1 :**

What I also tried is deleting the solution folder from computer B and recreate it (by doing a GetLatestVersion from TFS) without success.

**EDIT 2 :**

After publishing on the production server, if I manually copy `App_global.asax.compiled` and `App_global.asax.dll` in the \bin folder everything works as expected. So it is clear the problem is there.

Hope someone can help me on this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem, couple of files was missing in publish folder. All was working fine one month before. After i was spend all day of changing project settings i finally realise that the only different between now and then was windows compilation. After some windows update files and folders are shows those two little blue arrows on the top right of files pointing towards each other. This is compression indicator. **Everything was back to normal after I disable compression on solution and publish folder.**

Comment: I guess you are talking about ``NTFS compression``(https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-ntfs-compression-windows-10). This is not the case on my side. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This solved problem for me also when I removed compression from Asp net temp folders. Might be really timing problem caused by compression.

Answer (score 0):

I was the some problem. The partial solution was disable the antivirus avg and include the files in the publish.
Later change the antivirus for avast and the solution was perfect without disable the antivirus.

Comment: So your solution is to change to Avast anti-virus?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was due to a missing check for the "precompile during publishing" option. Once checked off, the App_global.asax.dll and App_global.asax.compiled magically reappeared in my deploy folder. I don't know the reason for this though.

[image: Publish options]